# IIS response with Content-Type: text throws an "Unhandled content type "null"" exception in Jsoup

Tags: java, http, scala, jsoup

I'm POSTing some data to an IIS server which replies with an simple id (here `1692945`):

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2011 17:08:37 GMT
Content-Length: 7

1692945
```

The `text` content type seems to confuse Jsoup which throws an:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unhandled content type "null" on URL http://domain.com/svr_listing.aspx. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml
```

Is there a way to specify that the response must be trated as `text/plain`? Is this a jsoup bug?

Thanks,

Nicolas

Comment: I don't think its a valid content type. I always thought they *had* to be a type and subtype, separated by a `/`.

Comment: Yes, I think that the problem is due to IIS sending a wrong Content-Type. So my question is to know if it's possible to specify the jsoup to explicitly interpret the response as text/plain.

Comment: Report it to the server admin of the website in question.

Comment: I'm building a scrapper to automate the postings of listings to a property listings portal. I don't know if the website owner likes that kind of automated interaction with their websites so I prefer being discrete...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jsoup checks the response type by default, to protect you from accidently trying to parse images and PDFs etc as HTML. Because it doesn't recognise `text` as a valid HTML content-type, it is throwing an exception.

You can force jsoup to ignore the content-type and parse the response as HTML with the [`Connection.ignoreContentType()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#ignoreContentType%28boolean%29) method.

E.g.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).get(); // or .post();
```

Comment: Wonderful! It's a shame that I didn't came on this option on my own! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup can read data from String objects. Why not use an InputStreamReader to read the server response into a String, then have JSoup parse the response?

Comment: As I'm using Scala I think that http://dispatch.databinder.net would be a great fit for the task.

Comment: Never heard of dispatcher.databinder.net before, looks like a great library!

Comment: I'm still a Scala n00b but it seems more natural than jsoup

Comment: Jsoup's strong point is that it was designed to deal with poorly written HTMLs, i.e., real-world html. How about Dispatch? How well does it handle mal-formatted html (i.e., an page with missing tags)?